# ganache-cli command not found

Tags: ganache-cli

I tried installing ganache-cli with yarn. Even though yarn has successfully installed ganache-cli, I bash can't find the ganache-cli.

```
smakbar@OMEN:~/cryptoCurrencies/web3$ yarn global add ganache-cli
yarn global v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "ganache-cli@6.12.2" with binaries:
      - ganache-cli
Done in 1.66s.
smakbar@OMEN:~/cryptoCurrencies/web3$ ganache-cli
ganache-cli: command not found
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Were you able to solve it? If yes how did you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same problem it is solved by

```
npm install -g ganache-cli
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks.  But why did the yarn install not work and this does???
Is anyone else as annoyed as I am re: all these package managers that fail to do their job?
I've been having so many issues for months w/ truffle, npm, nodjs, yarn, blahblah blah.
Seem like the whole world is broken when it comes to software installs.

Answer (score 0):

Running ganache with sudo worked for me. Try the following

```
sudo yarn global add ganache
```

Comment: using sudo as a fix is generally not a good idea.